# Inconsistent behavior with @EqualsAndHashCode between Eclipse JUnit4 and gradle test run

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit, lombok

I get different results when running unit tests with Eclipse JUnit and gradle test. Having a class like:

```
@Getter @Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class ObjectWithId {
    private Long id;
}
```

and a test like (compressed cases to one test to save space):

```
@Test
public void testObjectWithId() {

    ObjectWithId o1 = new ObjectWithId(), o2 = new ObjectWithId();
    o1.setId(1L);
    o2.setId(1L);
    assertEquals(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
    assertEquals(o1, o2);

    o2.setId(2L);
    assertNotEquals(o1, o2);
    assertNotEquals(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());

}
```

everything goes fine as expected.

Then, having a class like:

```
@Getter @Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class ObjectWithIdAndDate {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime created;

}
```

with a test like:

```
@Test
public void testObjectWithIdAndDate() {

    ObjectWithIdAndDate o1 = new ObjectWithIdAndDate(), o2 = new ObjectWithIdAndDate();
    o1.setId(1L);
    o2.setId(1L);
    assertEquals(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
    assertEquals(o1, o2);

    o2.setId(2L);
    assertNotEquals(o1, o2);
    assertNotEquals(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());

    o2.setId(1L);
    o2.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
    // Eclipse JUnit starts failing here because setting the created.
    // Gradle test will pass.
    assertEquals(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
    assertEquals(o1, o2);

    o1.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
    assertEquals(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
    assertEquals(o1, o2);

}
```

it fails when running with Eclipse JUnit but succeeds with gradle test? I run gradle test both from Eclipse and command line, no difference. So, it seems that somehow gradle knows better how `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` should be treated...?

I have `compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'` in my `build.gradle` and same version of lombok.jar installed in my Eclipse.

Both gradle project and Eclipse use JUnit version 4.12. What am I missing here?

Some further investigations:

I constructed otherwise identical project but with Maven. To my surprise JUnit test also pass with this project.

Does this smell like there is something wrong with Eclipse gradle project facet or some other gradle project specific setting?

Comment: Are you also using Eclipse's compiler?

Comment: Also your test is wrong; the second `setCreated` could never possibly equal the same `LocalDateTime`.  Isolate that into a variable and use that instead.

Comment: @Makoto I guess so, I run it by "Run as  JUnit test"

Comment: @Makoto `setCreated(..)` is there to test functionality of `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` so that if I understood it right it should never be considered in comparison. Whether true or not test results differ.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't noticed that.  It's just an instant smell for me when seeing someone use `LocalDateTime.now()` in two different places.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also update your Eclipse installation of lombok. You can verify the installed version in the Help > About Eclipse screen. In the white area, the bottom line should inform you of the installed version.

Run `java -jar lombok.jar` to update your installations.

Comment: Good observation. I did not put that in my question but I did it also as a very first attempt. Eclipse says it has 1.18.2. So it is not about version conflict with lombok.jar I think.

Comment: I just check your example with both lombok plugin 1.18.2 and the current edge 1.18.3, and both works as expected in Eclipse and maven. So it probably is an issue with the lombok plugin installation in your Eclipse. Could you try installing lombok to a fresh Eclipse installation and use a clean workspace?

Comment: It also works on my machine. How do you launch Eclipse? If you use a shortcut, please make sure that that's not using a different lombok version.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just as an update: I made a fresh install and the problem went away, so Eclipse & Lombok & workspace from scratch. Never found out what was the problem. I actually had this problem on two separate machines but I was unable to detect what was so special with these installations to make this difference.